# Changing "go to member" keymap in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to change the key mapping for "go to member" in IntelliJ (ctrl+shift+alt+n) but can't find it in the keymap settings.  Anyone know where/how to change this one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Go To Symbol". If you go to the keymap and type "symbol" in the search, you'll find it under the "Go To" menu.

Comment: Thanks! How did I miss that!? Strange that it never showed up when typing "go to" in the search filter.  And I must have been typing "member".  If you know of a shortcut to find symbols within the current file only, please let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can see all members of the current class with Ctrl+F12. Pressing it again will include all inherited members as well. Start typing a name to narrow down the list.